# Передавать ли параметры в методы класса, или устанавливать в свойства?

Tags: ооп, классы, php

В общем возник спор как писать класс. Я передаю в методы класса параметры, например

```
$myClass->search($str, $param1, $param2)
```

а товарищ говорит, что нужно все методы делать без параметров, а все брать из свойств. Т.е. перед вызовом метода класса, установить ему

```
$myClass->str = $str;
$myClass->param1 = $param1;
```

и вызывать

```
$myClass->search();
```

а внутри search уже брать эти параметры из

```
$this->str
```

и т.д. Мне такой способ кажется очень неудобным, но товарищ (он же начальник ))) мотивирует тем, что возможно для методов будут появляться разного рода необязательные параметры, и тогда запись прототипа и сам вызов будут выглядеть громоздко.

Кто как сам пишет?

Comment: Публичные свойства объекта, в большинстве случаев, зло. Если уж очень хочеться избавиться от аргументов, смотрите в сторону магических методов __set() и __get().

Comment: *"возможно для методов будут появляться .."*, а возможно и не будут. В общем случае тут не будет однозначного ответа - слишком много паттернов, которые работают и так и эдак. По крайней мере сейчас, у вас ограничено применение этих параметров, а то что предлагается - сделает их частью класса, и общее *состояние* будет уже сложнее.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь нужно помнить, что класс должен содержать в себе только те члены, которые действительно имеют отношение к моделируемой им сущности. Забивать его другими полями/свойствами только лишь из соображения, что "запись прототипа и сам вызов будут выглядеть громоздко" - это не слишком хорошо. Впрочем, передавать в метод 100500 параметров - идея ничуть не лучшая. Но тот факт, что ваш класс вынужден либо инкапсулировать эти самые 100500 полей, либо содержать методы с той же кучей аргументов, обычно говорит лишь о том, что ваш класс спроектирован неверно, и, по всей вероятности, берет на себя чересчур много работы, а следовательно, имеет смысл его разбить на несколько менее тяжеловесных сущностей.

> но товарищ (он же начальник )

впрочем, эта ценная ремарка может свести на нет все аргументы в этом споре

Answer (score 2):

[Методы-перехватчики **set() и** get()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) позволяют достаточно гибко работать со свойствами. Это очень похоже на то, что говорит ваш начальник с некоторыми нюансами.

```
class Foo() {
  // В этом массиве мы будем хранить данные, 
  // какие это будут данные - нам не важно
  private $_data = array();

  __construct() {}

  // Добавляем данные в наш массив
  __set( $key, $val ) {
    $this->_data[$key] = $val;
    return $this;
  }

  // Читаем данные из массива
  __get( $key ) {
    return $this->_data[$key];
  }

  search() {}
}
```

Работает это так:

```
$bar = new Foo();
$bar->str( 'aaaaaa' )
    ->param1( 'bbbbb' )
    ->param2( 'cccc' )
    ->search();
```

Можно улучшить класс, добавив проверку существования данных, чтобы избежать затирки данных или ошибки при чтении.

Answer (score -1):

Правильно говорит Ваш начальник.

Зашивать параметры в интерфейс метода - это плохая практика.

Чаще всего, лучше настроечные параметры задавать через свойства объекта.

Исключения составляют специфические методы, которые в принципе не могут иметь различное количество параметров. Ну, например, truncate(str) вряд ли будут другие параметры для усечения строки, если имеется в виду удаление всех пробелов слева и справа. Да и то, если объект, для которого вызывается этот метод - строка, то логичнее этот метод оставить тоже без параметров.

К тому же, если в вашем примере идет реализация базового абстрактного класса у которого подразумевается наличие нескольких наследников, которые будут делать различные виды поисков, то метод search с параметрами будет вообще как собаке пятая нога. А вот без параметров, класс может легко наследоваться и использовать в полной мере полиморфизм метода search